# cbind error when merging list containing empty data frames

Tags: r, merge, cbind

When trying this code., I got an error.
'a' is a list of dataframes consisting of data extracted from files in b. There are some empty dataframes/records in 'a':

```
b <- list.files(path=".", pattern=".xlsx")
c <- Map(cbind, b, a)
```

I got this error:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

Anyway I can rectify this issue?

Comment: can you check the `sapply(a, dim)` and `sapply(b, dim)`

Comment: If one list element is empty, do you want to keep that list element as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are empty list elements, we can remove those

```
i1 <- (sapply(b, nrow) > 0) & (sapply(a, nrow) > 0)
Map(cbind, b[i1], a[i1])
```

---

Or create the condition within `Map` itself

```
out <- Map(function(x, y) if(nrow(x) > 0 & nrow(y) > 0) cbind(x, y), b, a)
```

assuming that otherwise the corresponding `list` elements have the same number of rows

If we need to get the originaldataset in case one of them is empty, we can do

```
Map(function(x, y) if(is.null(x)|NROW(x) == 0) {
              y} else if(is.null(y)|NROW(y) == 0) {
              x} else cbind(x, y), 
          b, a)
```

#### data

```
a <- list(head(mtcars), data.frame(col1 = numeric(0)), head(iris))
b <- list(data.frame(col1 = numeric(0)), head(iris), head(mtcars))
```

Comment: Another possibility (depending on what they want) inside `Map()` would be `if(nrow(x) == 0) {return(y)}` and vice versa.

Comment: I tried `Map`, but got his error `Error in if (nrow(x) == 0) { : argument is of length zero`

Comment: @Jane If you check my example, it is working for me

Comment: @@Jane Can you try my updated version of `Map` with `is.null`

Comment: @akrun it works now, but as I am trying to use rbind subsequently, I had this error `Error in rbindlist(a, fill = TRUE) : 
  Item 2 of input is not a data.frame, data.table or list` how can I remove those null records e.g. Item 2?

Comment: @Jane Just use `rbindlist(a[!sapply(a, is.null)], fill = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

You can check for rows in `a` and if it is empty `cbind` the two dataframes `else` return the original one.

```
Map(function(x, y) if (nrow(y)) cbind(x, y) else x, b, a)
```